# Netbeans with MySql - Database not working with other computers

Tags: java, mysql

I'm having an issue with Netbeans and a database from MySql. I have the proper libraries for the connector and such because it works completely fine on the home computer (which has the database.sql file on it). However when I transfer the 'dist' folder which contains the executable .jar file and the lib folder (containing the database connector) and run it on a different computer, the commands I had for selecting items from the database are completely blank. Does anyone have a solution? This is for a computer programming class and my teacher is the one who is making us use MySql for this project yet I've heard that it requires a local server on the new computer, which would render the program I have useless. She wouldn't give us these guidelines if it weren't possible, so if there is anyone with a proper solution, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Can you please include of the commands you're entering, along with any corresponding errors please?

Comment: Well the connection I'm using is:Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/chutesandladders", "root", "password");

Comment: There are no errors when it runs, but like I said, when I query the database, there is nothing selected. Here's one of the queries which selects a random question: ResultSet rsq = stmt.executeQuery("select Question from questions where idQuestion = " + ranNum);

Comment: did you publish the DB correctly to MySQL in the new computer? what is the content of database.sql? open it by notepad.

Comment: The application is a virtual chutes and ladders game and we will need to be able to distribute it to any sort of user. It needs to be setup to where any computer than can download the .jar file is able to run it. The user/player is not expected to have MySql and this is where I run into the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by content of the .sql file? Do you need the source code? It would be too long to post here with the character limit. I'm new to this site so I'm not sure how I would get that to you

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you hard coded the DB path.

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/chutesandladders", "root", "password");
```

The best approach is to have the arguments to this call configurable. That is, [read from a config file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) or take it in as command-line parameters.

**Example** Assuming we go the config file route (read the doc for Java's `Properties` class I linked above), and that you have properly loaded a `Properties` object into a variable `cfgFile` your code snippet above then becomes:

```
DriverManager.getConnection(cfgFile.getProperty("dbconstr"), cfgFile.getProperty("dbuser"), cfgFile.getProperty("dbpass"));
```

Far from the cleanest design but should do the trick.

When working with `Properties`, you need to also know how to read a file/open file `InputStream` objects.

Using command line parameters is a bit simpler but that is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Fairly new to programming, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: @Cam you need to replace the IP address to make the connection possible. Using localhost only works on the server. Find the home machine's address and hardcode it instead of localhost.

Comment: @SJan And this would allow other computers to access the database if the code has the home computer's IP?

Comment: @Cam Yes, plus you need to ensure that both TCP & UDP 3306 are open.